# Can I change the shortcut to change the keyboard layout to shift + alt?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 13.10

Whenever i try to change it to Shift + Alt the shortcut gets disabled...

Never mind, it is already reported as a bug at lunchpad :      https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1218322

Comment: As this is a known bug I'm voting to close. Don't forget to click "Affects me too" on the bug report as it increases the priority developers give to fixing it.